# How can I pass data to a required vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to follow this example code https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#using-example-application

I already made a controller with this code:

```
public function send()
{
    $orderId = 5;
    broadcast(new TestEvento($orderId));
    return view('test.send');
}

public function receive()
{
    $orderId = 5;
    return view('test.receive', compact('orderId'));
}
```

An event with this code:

```
public $orderId;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($orderId)
{
    $this->orderId = $orderId;
    Log::debug('Construct orderId: '.$orderId);
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    Log::debug('broadcastOn: '.$this->orderId);
    return new PrivateChannel('canaltest.'.$this->orderId);
}
```

A route:

```
Broadcast::channel('canaltest.{var}', function ($user, $var) {
    return true; //temp workaround
    return $user->id === Order::findOrNew($var)->user_id;
});
```

A view with this:

```
<div id="app">
    <test :orderId="{{$orderId}}"></test>
</div>
```

Added this line to app.js:

```
Vue.component('test', require('./components/Test.vue').default);
```

And a .vue with

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
        }
    }

    Echo.private('canaltest.${orderId}')
        .listen('TestEvento', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
</script>
```

The problem is I just can't find a way to get the js to get the orderId var and there's nowhere in vue documentation that says where should I place the .props array when requiring a component in app.js. So how can I get my test.vue component to read the orderId var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for as below for test.vue

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
          orderId: {
            type: [Number, String],
            required: true
          },
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: orderId is not defined" error

Comment: Are you passing the orderId from the parent component? Try to send the static orderId for now and then make it dyanmic.

Comment: I managed to make it work declaring the var in the blade template but I think this could be easily hacked by any user:

<script>
    var orderId = {{$orderId}};
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

Comment: Hope answer helps you to pass the data to child component.

Comment: I already solved it by assigning this.orderId value under the console.log() line. Thank you very much.